# insert file on bar using ant

Tags: xml, ant, build, broker

I am trying to make a ANT XML that build, override and deploy a bar file. It's working fine but I need to insert a file inside the folder META-INF (service.bar > service.appzip > META-INF) and i really don't know how to do it using ANT.

This is my ANT XML:

```
<project name="service" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <antcall target="build" />
        <antcall target="override" />
        <antcall target="deploy" />
    </target>

    <target name="build" >
        <loadfile property="toolkit.home" srcfile="toolkit_home.txt" />
        <loadfile property="workspace.dir" srcfile="workspace_dir.txt" />
        <loadfile property="broker.home" srcfile="broker_home.txt" />
        <exec executable="${toolkit.home}\mqsicreatebar.exe" spawn="false">
            <arg value="-data" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}" />
            <arg value="-b" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}\GeneratedBarFiles\service.ANT.bar" />
            <arg value="-p" />
            <arg value="service" />
            <arg value="-a" />
            <arg value="service\" />
            <arg value="-deployAsSource" />
        </exec>

    </target>

    <target name="override">
        <loadfile property="toolkit.home" srcfile="toolkit_home.txt" />
        <loadfile property="workspace.dir" srcfile="workspace_dir.txt" />
        <loadfile property="broker.home" srcfile="broker_home.txt" />
        <exec executable="${toolkit.home}\mqsiapplybaroverride.exe" spawn="false">
            <arg value="-b" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}\GeneratedBarFiles\service.ANT.bar" />
            <arg value="-p" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}\Scripts\build\properties\service.properties" />
            <arg value="-k" />
            <arg value="service" />
            <arg value="-r" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <loadfile property="toolkit.home" srcfile="toolkit_home.txt" />
        <loadfile property="workspace.dir" srcfile="workspace_dir.txt" />
        <loadfile property="broker.home" srcfile="broker_home.txt" />
        <exec executable="${broker.home}\mqsideploy.exe" spawn="false">
            <arg value="-i" />
            <arg value="10.0.0.1" />
            <arg value="-p" />
            <arg value="2424" />
            <arg value="-q" />
            <arg value="QM_01" />
            <arg value="-e" />
            <arg value="EG_06" />
            <arg value="-a" />
            <arg value="${workspace.dir}\GeneratedBarFiles\service.ANT.bar" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem unzip bar file, unzip appzip, copy the txt file to the folder, zip appzip and then zip bar file.

I tried out to use the command  but it doesn't work how I wanted.